# Prevent display html tags in comments

Tags: html

I was looking for a way to prevent display html tags in comments
for example if user put a html tags like `<br>` or `<hr>` dont display a horizontal line or line break just show as it was(print out put: `<br> or <hr>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent this. This will also prevent [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

http://codepad.viper-7.com/w5U8qs

Comment: i re-correct my answer, is there a way to just use br tags not anyelse